# Error: Could not find or load main class com.rsp.game.Game

Tags: java, launch

Before you mark this as a duplicate, I'd like to say that I've visited probably every thread made on the subject and still can't find a solution. I tried reinstalling JRE, configuring my classpath, etc. I've tried every solution I found but it still doesn't work. I can launch the program just fine using my IDE but it won't launch when trying to execute the jar file. I tried launching it with a .bat file and via command prompt. Here is my Manifest file:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Class-Path: C:\Users\Badr\IdeaProjects\JavaGame1\src\com\rsp\game\Game.java
Main-Class: com.rsp.game.Game
```

And yes, I do have the main method included in my Game class. I've heard that the main class shouldn't be included in a package but I don't know if that's true or not.

Comment: How are you trying to execute? It sounds like you're creating a jar and try to run that? Like in `java -jar yourjarfile.jar `?

Comment: @VolkerKueffel Yes, that's exactly what I'm doing.

Comment: And when you run `jar -ft yourjarfile.jar` it shows com/rsp/game/Game.class?

Comment: @VolkerKueffel No it only shows the Manifest file.

Comment: Well, there you go. If you don't package your classes into the jar you can't run them from there. You can still run your code if you cd into JavaGame1 and execute `java -cp . com.rsp.game.Game`. If you want to run if from the jar you obviously have to build your jar correctly first.

Comment: @VolkerKueffel Thank you I completely overlooked the fact that I forgot to include the compiled output into my jar. However, it stills gives me the same error even though my main class shows up when I run "jar -ft jarfile.jar"
Here's a picture: http://i63.tinypic.com/65coz4.png

Comment: Sorry man, I'm out of ideas. There is something wrong with the way you build the jar or your code, but I can't figure it out. Does `java -cp . com.rsp.game.Game` work on the top level of your build directory? You can also remove the Class-Path from your manifest, it's not needed there, but I doubt that would cause that error even if it's completely wrong. Maybe you try using build tools like Maven or Gradle, they would make sure that the jar is built correctly. Somewhat of a learning curve though, but worth it long term. I haven't created a jar file manually in years...

Comment: @VolkerKueffel Nope not even `java -cp . com.rsp.game.Game` works. And how would I go about using Maven or Gradle when I've already made the project? Is it still possible to implement it?

Comment: @VolkerKueffel THANK YOU. I solved it by removing the Class-Path like you said. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Your `Class-Path` is **incorrect**; it needs to be set to the folder that contains `com` (because the directory structure is part of the fully qualified class name), and you need to ***compile*** your `.java` source files to `class` files.

> I've heard that the main class shouldn't be included in a package but I don't know if that's true or not.

That is not true, but the main class name must be fully qualified (and `Main-Class: com.rsp.game.Game` **is**).

Comment: I found a directory in my project that stores the .class files, however it still gives me the same error with the following classpath: 
C:\Users\Badr\IdeaProjects\JavaGame1\out\production\JavaGame1

Comment: The directory that stores com, which stores rsp, which stores game, which stores Game.class; you need to point to the parent folder of com.

Comment: Yeah JavaGame1 contains com which contains rsp which contains game which contains Game.class.